# Overloading baseclass assignment operator in subclass class leads to ambiguous assignment error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have this base class (details removed)

```
template<class T>
class GPtr
{
public:
    typedef T BaseType;

    GPtr& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        m_p = rhs.get();
        return *this;
    }
private:
    BaseType m_p;
};
```

Then a sub-class specialises the template and adds another assignment option:

```
class GDrawablePtr : public GPtr<XYZ>
{
public:
    GDrawablePtr& operator=(const RootType& rhs)
    {
        GPtr::operator =(convert<BaseType::element_type>(rhs));
        return *this;
    }
/* -- only compiles if this is uncommented
    GDrawablePtr& operator=(const BaseType& rhs)
    {
        GPtr::operator =(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
*/
};
```

With that code commented out, I get compilation errors about ambiguous assignment when assigning instances. If I uncomment it, then even though it doesn't appear to do anything new, compilation is successful.

Is there a way to avoid re-defining the original base assignment operator, and what is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's known as *hiding*: declaring a function in a derived class makes any function in the base class with the same name inaccessible. You can use a *using-declaration* to make the base class versions available too:

```
// In GDrawablePtr
using GPtr::operator=;
```